# Memory leak due to undetached events inside BackgroundService

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, event-handling, .net-5

I have a memory leak caused by the code below, probably due to undetached events, and I don't know how to properly unsubscribe from them.

I have the interface **IEventsHandler**, declared as singleton, which exposes some events. This interface is used inside a **BackgroundService**, where a subscriber is attached to the event. When an **AlertEvent** occurs, a scope is created to use a service which stores the event inside the database.

Here is the code:

```
public class MyWorker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IEventsHandler _eventsHandler;
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public MyWorker(IEventsHandler eventsHandler,
                    IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _eventsHandler = eventsHandler;
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        _eventsHandler.AlertOccurred += AlertEventOccurred;
    }

    private async void AlertEventOccurred(object sender, AlertEvent e)
    {
        using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
        var service = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<AlertService>();
        await service.SaveAlert(e);
    }
}

public interface IEventsHandler
{
    event EventHandler<AlertEvent> AlertOccurred;
    Task AddAlertEventAsync(AlertEvent ev);
}

public class EventsHandler : IEventsHandler
{
    public event EventHandler<AlertEvent> AlertOccurred;
    
    public async Task AddAlertEventAsync(AlertEvent ev)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => AlertOccurred?.Invoke(this, ev));
    }
}
```

PS any advice on bad practices used in the example code is welcome :-)

Thanks

Comment: What makes you think that this is the cause of a memory leak? A Background service will only create one copy behind the scenes, meaning you should only be subscribing once.

Comment: A large number of SO questions that start with _"I have a memory leak caused by..."_ turn out to be misunderstandings rather than leaks. What evidence do you have of a "leak" and why do you think it's caused by _"undetached events"_?

Comment: I noticed that my application in a testing environment was consuming a large amount of memory and, doing some testing, I saw that the memory was increasing generating new events. So, I googled a bit and found that memory leaks can occur when you don't unsubscribe from events. But surely I could be wrong and not be in the case of a "memory leak".

Comment: Anyway, you think there are errors in the posted code considering that "MyWorker" exist for the lifetime of application?

Answer (score 1):

[BackgroundService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#backgroundservice-base-class) implements [IHostedService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostedservice?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) interface which has a couple of methods named `StartAsync` and `StopAsync`.
It's better to use these methods instead of class constructor to subscribe to your events and then unsubscribe from them.
This way

```
public override Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    _eventsHandler.AlertOccurred += AlertEventOccurred;
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

public override Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    _eventsHandler.AlertOccurred -= AlertEventOccurred;
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

If this is actually the cause of your memory leak, the fix is pretty simple. Just create a destructor and unsubscribe from the event.

A destructor is the opposite of a constructor in that it gets called right before the object gets garbage collected. It's denoted by a tilde (`~`) preceding the same syntax as a constructor (minus the parameters). Yours would look something like this:

```cs
~MyWorker(){
    _eventsHandler.AlertOccurred -= AlertEventOccurred;
}
```

Comment: That is a **terrible**. C# Finalizers should never touch managed objects. By the time the Finalizer runs, there is no guarantee that managed objects referenced by the object being finalized still exist.

Comment: @Flydog57 If you have a better suggestion, be my guest. If it doesn't exist then wrapping it in a `try...catch` would handle that. I don't see any issues with it.